# iOS 7 How to seque to an UISearchDisplay with focus

Tags: iphone, ios7, uisearchbar

I am trying to seque from a view controller to a uisearchbar that has focus or is animated.

The uisearchbar and uisearchdisplay is part of a uitableviewcontroller.

Example:

- ViewController A has a search button that will segue to ViewController B.
- ViewController B is a TableViewController with a SearchBar and Search Display Controller.
- When the segue is preformed want the Search Display Controller to be animated on View Controller B

Let me know if anyone needs more details.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem.

In View Controller B, I added the following property:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL animateSearchBar;
```

Then in the prepareForSegue method in View Controller A, I added:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender  
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MainSearchButton"])
    {
        ResponseTableViewController *nextController = (ResponseTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        nextController.animateSearchBar = YES;
    }
}
```

Then in the viewDidLoad method in View Controller B, I added:

```
if (self.animateSearchBar)
{
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive: YES animated: YES];
}
```